# React acting weird (compiled with problems 9 errors)

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mern

I've been working with react using mern stack. Everything was fine until I used JSON.parse in a function when getting data out of the mongo database. I clicked save and I got 9 errors. I removed all the code, everything relating to it as if I never attempted it and I'm still getting these 9 errors shown below:

Any pointers?

Compiled with problems:X

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/cookie-signature/index.js 4:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/cookie-signature'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 15:17-41

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/destroy'


ERROR in ./node_modules/destroy/index.js 19:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/destroy'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "zlib": require.resolve("browserify-zlib") }'
    - install 'browserify-zlib'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "zlib": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 18:13-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/etag'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/etag/index.js 20:12-31

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/etag'


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/response.js 25:11-26

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "http": require.resolve("stream-http") }'
    - install 'stream-http'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "http": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/express/lib/utils.js 31:18-40

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'querystring' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/express/lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "querystring": require.resolve("querystring-es3") }'
    - install 'querystring-es3'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "querystring": false }


ERROR in ./node_modules/mime/mime.js 3:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/mime'


ERROR in ./node_modules/send/index.js 29:9-22

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/sebastianrichards/ReactProject/client/node_modules/send'
```

Comment: My guess it's an `npm` problem rather than a React one. Please post your package.json & package-lock.json

Comment: for some reason I can't edit this post but I reuploaded the question with the json files if you click on my profile and check it out I'll appreciate it a lot

Comment: I solved it, I removed import { json } from 'express/lib/response'; from the imports on one of the react files and it worked

Comment: You can post the above comment & accept it is an answer (for future readers who have the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean install of **npm** by deleting `/node_modules` and running `npm install`. Also check that the package in the error exists within your `package.json`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, I removed import { json } from 'express/lib/response'; from the imports on one of the react files and it worked